# Python Requests-HTML extracting SRC

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

wondering if anyone can help. I've searched the docs for requests-html but no luck https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

Previously I was using requests and beautiful soup but the website I'm scraping has now implemented javascript. I've managed to extract text using Requests-HTML but am unsure of how to extract image SRC

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
R = session.get(SHOPURL,headers=headers)
images = R.html.find(#website information)
for image in images:
    print(image)
```

For each image that exists this is what is returned

```
<Element 'img' _ngcontent-app-c164='' deferload=''>
```

image filenames on website are stored under 'src"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are lazy loading, and behind an API request that must be authenticated with header information

Answer (score 2):

The [`attrs`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.Element.attrs) attribute of the `Element` class is what you're looking for - it's a dict containing all of the attributes of the Element. For an `img` Element (or tag), the `"src"` attribute will contain the path to the image. So:

```py
for image in images:
    src = image.attrs["src"]
    print(src)


Output:
/img/logo.png
/img/header.png
http://www.website.com/img/hero_background.png
...
```

Comment: Thanks MattDMo for your response, I've tried to implement and am getting a KeyError: 'src'

Even though though there is definitely an src

Comment: calling attrs by itself just returns {'_ngcontent-app-c164': '', 'deferload': ''}

Comment: @HJB what does the actual HTML code look like in the page source? Is there a `src` attribute in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: You cant access the img tags via the page source, inspecting yields

<img _ngcontent-app-c164="" deferload="" src=" imageURL " srcset=" imageURL, imageURL, imageURL " sizes="(min-width:  640px), (min-width: 970px), (max-width:  640px)">

Comment: researching more could this be linked to lazy loading?

Comment: @HJB given the `deferload` parameter, that's probably it. I don't know much about AngularJS (the source of all the `_ng...` tags and parameters you see), so I don't know what it takes to trigger loading. You may want to look into using a headless browser like PhantomJS, or check out the `selenium` package.